# External value usage in Datamapper - WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

A data format with:

```
Item: A
Id: 001
Price: 100.00
```

Should be converted into:

```
ItemName: A
ItemId: 001
Price: 100.00 * (1 + 0.1) ---->(here the price should be calculated with commision)
```

Here commision is 0.1, should come from a static property (not constant but the commission may change daily) externally. How can I fix this using WSO2 ESB DataMapper?